# Problemas com responsividade bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto, mas estou com problemas em questões de responsividade, quando o site muda para diferentes tela como: celulares, tablets e outros dispositivos. Ele quebra todo o seu layout, estou usando o bootstrap e as suas tags, porém estou com algumas dificuldades sobre o entendimento do mesmo.

Investidor

```
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/meu-estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,400i,600,700|Raleway:300,400,400i,500,500i,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/nivo-slider/css/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/owlcarousel/owl.transitions.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/animate/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/venobox/venobox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/parallax/parallax.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/easing/easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/nivo-slider/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/appear/jquery.appear.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lib/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/contactform/contactform.js"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/main.js"></script>

    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>      

    <header>
        <!-- header-area start -->
        <div  class="header-area">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">

                        <!-- Navigation -->
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <!-- Brand -->
                                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll sticky-logo" href="index.html">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/imgBlue/logoUltra.png" class="Logo">
                                    <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
                                    <!-- <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" title=""> -->
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-menu bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" id="navbar-example">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav  " style="margin-left:395px;">
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="page-scroll " href="/index"><b>A Blue</b></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="page-scroll" href="/negocios"><b>Nossos Negócios</b></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="page-scroll" href="/investir"><b>Porque Investir</b></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="page-scroll" href="/social"><b>Blue Social</b></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="page-scroll" href="/contato"><b>Contato</b></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!-- navbar-collapse -->
                        </nav>
                        <!-- END: Navigation -->
                        <div onclick="scrollToTop" class="retangulo">
                            <a class="arrumarInvestidor" href="/investidor"><b>Área do Investidor</b></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- header-area end -->
    </header>
    <!-- header end -->


    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/imgBlue/ImagemBlueBackGround.jpg" class="">                    


                <form class="w3-container w3-card-4" action="/action_page.php" style="
                      position: absolute;
                      bottom: 218px;
                      left: 439px;
                      ">


                    <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="first" type="text" style="
                           width: 489px;
                           height: 53px;
                           " placeholder="Usuário">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="last" type="text" style="
                           width: 489px;
                           height: 53px;
                           " placeholder="Senha">
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" style="
                            float: left;
                            margin-left: 138px;
                            width: 243px;
                            height: 53px;
                            ">Entrar</button>

                </form>


            </div>


        </div>
    </div>

     <footer>
        <div class="footer-area" style="background-color: #c7c8ca;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">


                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="abluefooter"><b><a href="/index">A blue</a></b></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/index#quemSomos">Quem somos</a> </h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/index#atuacao">Atuação</a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo">Core Business</h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/index#valores">Valores </a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/index#qualificaoTecnica">Qualifação técnica</a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/index#parceiros">Parceiros</a></h5></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">

                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="nossos"><b><a href="/negocios">Nossos negócios</a></b></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/negocios#linhaTempo">Linha do tempo</a></h5></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">

                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="nossos"><a href="/investir">Porque Investir</a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="m"><a href="/investir#modeloInvestimentos">Modelo de investimentos</a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/investir#vantagens">Vantagens</a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/investir#modeloNegocio">Modelo de negócio</a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/investir#compliance">Compilance</a></h5></div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-2">

                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="nossos"><a href="/social">Blue Social</a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="m"><a href="/social#blueSocial">Responsabilidade Social</a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/social#comoFunciona">Como funciona</a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/social#instituicoes">Instituições</a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/social#apoiamAcausa">Eles apoiam a causa</a></h5></div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-2">

                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="nossos"><a href="/contato">Contato</a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/contato#conosco">Compramos seu terreno </a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/contato#conosco">Trabalhe conosco</a></h5></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h5 class="tudo"><a href="/contato#localizacao">Localização</a></h5></div>
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="col-md-5"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/imgBlue/logoUltra.png" class="logoFooter"></div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <p class="a"><b>BLUE</b></p>
                    <p class="rua">Rua Kalil Elias Warde, 219 </p>
                    <p class="ruaCampina">Campina do Siqueira - Curitiba - PR</p>
                    <p class="number">(41) 3090.3690 &nbsp;(41) 3090.3662</p>
                    <p class="e">contato@blueempreendimentos.com.br</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </footer>

</body>
```

link da tela do site: http://blueholding.hqssolucoes.com.br/investidor/

Comment: Cara isso é um Template de WordPress, tem um tanto de classe que não é do Bootstrap, e o código que vc postou ai não fica nem de perto similar ao código que está no link que vc postou... Além disso parece que tb tem classes do `w3css` misturadas com `bootstrap`. Recomendo que edite sua pergunta e coloque o código de forma mínima que de para simular seu problema

Answer (score 1):

Entendendo o conceito de linhas e colunas no grid você pode ter uma melhor compreensão de como montar o seus layouts de forma que a responsividade não fique deformada.

No seu código você criou um sistema de grid que ocupa metade das colunas no centro usando um col-md-6, ou seja para acima de 1200px o content ficará dividido entre duas partes. Note também que nesse código você não criou linha para delimitar verticalmente os seus conteúdos.

Portanto, foque em criar um container normal primeiro, depois você cria uma row dentro desse container, e dentro da rol você vai delimitando as colunas.

```
<div class="container fixed col-lg-4 col-sm-2">
              <div id = "rowAttribute"class="row products justify-content-center">
                   <div class = "col-md-3"> aqui ficará um conteudo que ocupará 1/3 das 12 colunas do grid </div>
                   <div class = "col-md-3"> aqui ficará um conteudo que ocupará 1/3 das 12 colunas do grid</div>
                   <div class = "col-md-3"> aqui ficará um conteudo que ocupará 1/3 das 12 colunas do grid</div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Compartilho um link que vai te ajudar muito no entendimento dos grids.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background

Comment: Muito bom site, tudo muito bem explicado!